# Загрузка сцены после нажатия кнопки с клавиатуры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d, unity3d-editor

у меня есть некая сцена с Canvas на ней. Есть C# код. Этот код я привязал к главной камере. Код ниже.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour

{
[SerializeField] KeyCode keyOne;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
void Enter()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(keyOne))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Random.Range(1, 4));
    }
}
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия кнопки Enter с клавиатуры грузилась следующая сцена. Я не понимаю, как мне это реализовать. А так же мне не понятно, почему кнопка Escape реагирует на закрытие игры а Enter нет... Клавиатура работает исправно.

[image: Порядок сцен.]

Думаю скриншот играет какую-то роль.

Заранее огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: А кто и когда вызывает `Enter`?
Может быть вызывать `Enter` в update?

Comment: Полезное чтение: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: Сергей Сквортсов, спасибо большое, ваш совет работает!!

Comment: Отдельное спасибо вам за ссылку на литературу, обязательно прочитаю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение Сергея мне помогло. Всё что требовалось—переместить из `void Enter()` строчки

```
    if (Input.GetKey(keyOne))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Random.Range(1, 4));
    }
```

в метод `void Update()`.